# Show complete documentation in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Jupyter Notebook shows the complete documentation on shift + tab.
Is there a way I can get the same with vscode?

Ctrl + shift + space only provides methods signature.

Edit: I am hoping to see something like this

[image]

Comment: does `CTRL + SPACE` work for what you expect?

Comment: @soulshined, no. `Ctrl + space` only show suggestions.

Comment: it should show suggestions and details (which is a form of documentation in vscode), if you don't have suggestions for the given method I'm not sure

Comment: Not fully sure if this is what you are looking for. But I'm a developer on the Python extension. We have this issue in our backlog here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7850
Might want to upvote that, as that is how we look at what to work on next.

Comment: @IanHuff, I realized `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` shows full documentation on some methods (like `pd.read_pickle`) and on some don't (like `pd.read_csv`). The link you provided does answer the question. If you can place it as an answer I can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 21):

Just started using the **Docs View** extension, and it is awesome!
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.docs-view

It puts the documentation you usually see on hover in the side panel. (I learned about it from this [tweet](https://twitter.com/mattbierner/status/1501992696302342144?s=20&t=X91mFFowqNit0HQg6cbdYA))

[image]
[image]

Works in the notebook view, too!
[image]

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem. The only solution I found is to use "?" at the end of the function like,

`np.random.randint?` run

[image]

Comment: I think this should be selected as the answer since no other solution is found unfortunately!

Comment: vscode should show this on hover, or at least provide a menu item or something

Answer (score 4):

I have recently been trying to get to use VSCode with Jupyter Notebooks as well and for me (on macOS, I assume it would be the same for Windows) all I have to do is hover the mouse on top of the method I wanna get the documentation for and wait a little bit, and it'll pop up.

Please take a look at the image below (since this is my first answer I can't embed the picture, but you should be able to click the link to have a look).

[image: VSCode documentation popup]

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the extension: `Pylance`.

If you want to view related information, you could find it in the folder under the module that you need to install in the created virtual environment.

For example, using the module '`pandas`', you can find file '`parsers.py`' in '`.venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io`', which contains relevant parsed content.

[image]

Reference: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Answer (score 1):

As Caner Erden pointed out, you can use Pythons base functionality of typing a '?', just make sure you do it before the method, not after.

This will give you the complete documentation you are looking for, just within the code cell, unfortunately not a pop out window like Jupyter Notebook.

[Example of documentation in vscode-jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM9gu.png)

This contextual help issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1307) on vscode-jupyter GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I can't read all the lines; so I click the method then shift f12 open definition to the side.  Then if I hover, I can read all the lines.